# Facebook App, Posting to Users' Wall Concept

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a little Facebook app that posts to people's walls when they have a birthday coming up. This is all good, but there's a concept I'm not quite understanding.

I'm using a cron job to run a script that searches through users and posts to the ones that have birthdays on that day. I've created a Facebook account for the app so the post should be under the apps account. What I'm confused on is how is the script going to know to post from the app's Facebook account? Do I need to log in through the script somehow? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the answer!  Yes - you are correct, the application needs to use a certain `access_token` to performa actions "on-behalf" of the application.
You should read the [Facebook Authentication Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) under the header - "App Login" to learn how to obtain the app access token.  After you have this token the methods you use to publish post are identical to regular posts.